# Stuck on add calculation to SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a problem that i need help with, i know where the issue lies but i cant get it to work.

The SQL table column poci.Value is of datatype nvarchar, and what i want to do is to calculate the value that im fetching with * 1.5 in the select statement.

The value of poci.value is 2.6, so when i run the query (see below), i get 2.6 as result as expected. And i just wanted to add a calculation to the result with * 1.5, but this wont work since u cant calculate nvarchar like that..

This is how the query looks without any attempted calculation:

```
SELECT poci.Value
FROM ProductionOrder po
LEFT JOIN Product p
    ON p.ProductionOrderId = po.ProductionOrderId
LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderConfiguration poc
    ON poc.ProductionOrderId = po.ProductionOrderId and poc.Valid = 1
LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderConfigurationItem poci
    ON poci.ProductionOrderConfigurationId = poc.ProductionOrderConfigurationId
WHERE p.ProductId = #ProductId# and poci.Name = 'C_UE'
```

I tried to add this to the start of query but that wont work:

```
DECLARE @Calc decimal(6,2) SET @Calc = 1.5 SELECT poci.value * @Calc AS test etc. etc..
```

Please help me im really stuck here!

Link to tabledata:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHnjd.jpg

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN's make no sense... Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: OK! So i will try to make it as clear as possible, this is a SS of the table  data, the 2.6 is the value that i want to add a calculation to in the select statement.  The column "Value" is of datatype NVARCHAR(255).

Comment: Are you sure poci.value contains '2.6' (and not other non numeric characters)?   If you try this, it works: `DECLARE @Calc decimal(6,2) SET @Calc = 1.5 SELECT (CAST ('2.6' AS NVARCHAR)) * @Calc`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @etsa , however the poci.value can contain other values and not just 2.6 , for example it can contain 2.8, but the calculation of * 1.5 should always be applied regardless, so can you tell me what it should look like to make that work? And YES i understand that its really bad that this column "Value" has datatype NVARCHAR, but this is the way the db is setup and im not allowed to change this.

Comment: That was just an example to let you look the real cause of the problem.  SQL-SERVER in that case makes implicit conversion of varchar value to make the calculus.  But it can't do that if the value is not numeric (try to substitute '2.6' with '2.6a' to my previous code and see its effect.

Comment: It gives me: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: I will add this comment as i replied to other user here:  There is non-numeric data in poci.Value , however the query will always return a value that is a number example "X.X". To be clear, the column poci.value has other values stored, such as YES, NO etc, thats why its a NVARCHAR datatype, when they made the database they made it like this.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(poci.Value AS DECIMAL) * 1.5
```

Etc.

Or:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS
SELECT poci.Value AS val
FROM [the rest of your original query];
SELECT CAST(val AS DECIMAL(6,2)) * 1.5 FROM temp;
```

Comment: It gives me error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2.6' to data type int.

Comment: same problem still.

Comment: There's also `SELECT CONVERT(poci.Value, DECIMAL) * 1.5`, but that does the same thing. And you're sure there's no non-numeric data in `poci.Value`...(?)

Comment: There is non-numeric data in poci.Value , however the query will always return a value that is a number example "X.X".   To be clear, the column poci.value has other values stored, such as YES, NO etc, thats why its a NVARCHAR datatype, when they made the database they made it like this.

Comment: There might be an issue where it doesn't guarantee the order the clauses are evaluated in, so the non-numeric data is a problem. A couple other things to try: add `WHERE poci.Value REGEXP '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$'` (or `ISNUMERIC(poci.Value)` if your SQL engine allows); or create temporary table with `poci.Value` filtered to be only numeric and then do 2nd query with `CAST()`.

Comment: How would this "temp" table query look like? to get the result of the idea you had there?

Comment: I added to answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these (MSSQL):

```
DECLARE @CALC AS DECIMAL(6,2);
SET @CALC=1.5;
WITH TEST_DATA AS (SELECT CAST('2.6' AS NVARCHAR) AS VALUE UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2.8' AS NVARCHAR)  UNION ALL SELECT CAST('YES' AS NVARCHAR))
SELECT VALUE
    , VALUE * @CALC AS NEW_VALUE
FROM TEST_DATA
WHERE ISNUMERIC(VALUE)>0
;
```

Output:

```
VALUE                          NEW_VALUE
------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
2.6                            3.9000
2.8                            4.2000
```

Or

```
DECLARE @CALC AS DECIMAL(6,2);
SET @CALC=1.5;
WITH TEST_DATA AS (SELECT CAST('2.6' AS NVARCHAR) AS VALUE UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2.8' AS NVARCHAR)  UNION ALL SELECT CAST('YES' AS NVARCHAR))
SELECT VALUE
    , CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(VALUE)>0 THEN CAST( VALUE * @CALC AS NVARCHAR) ELSE VALUE END AS NEW_VALUE
FROM TEST_DATA
;
```

Output:

```
VALUE                          NEW_VALUE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
2.6                            3.9000
2.8                            4.2000
YES                            YES
```